# Spring @PathVariable returns HTTP Status 404

Tags: spring

What I'm trying to do retrieve a user by their id and also retrieve the modules assigned to them on a page. I have mapped the one to many relationship in the models.

User Model

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "user")
 @Component
  public class User implements Serializable
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user")
  private Set<Module> sModule = new HashSet<Module>();

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="manager")
  private Set<Module> cModule = new HashSet<Module>();
```

Module model

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "modules")
  @Component
  public class Module implements Serializable
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private User user;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
  @JoinColumn(name="manager_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private User manager;
```

Controller for it -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home/user_page/{userId}", method = 

    RequestMethod.GET)  
public String showUserModules(@PathVariable("userId") String userId, ModelMap 

    map, HttpServletRequest request) {
    map.addAttribute("cp", request.getContextPath());
    map.addAttribute("user", userService.getWithModules(userId));

    return "/home/user_page";}
```

When I try to open the user_page it returns an error showing:

```
    The requested resource is not available
```

So how do I get the user and the required modules for them when I go their user page.

Edit: Stacktrace

```
   WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP 

  request with URI [/professional/home/user_page] in DispatcherServlet 

  with name 'servlet-context'
```

Comment: Hello. What URL do you use when you get this error?

Comment: What's the actual stacktrace?

Comment: Hi, I have added the stacktrace to the first post. It was a one line warning about no mapping found for HTTP request with the URI.

Comment: Could you be more clear with provided URLs? You publish already 3 different URLs: `localhost:8080/project/home/user/setting_page`, `localhost:8080/project/home/user/{userId}`, `/professional/home/user_page` (last from your StackTrace) and none of them mapped to the `/home/user_page/{userId}`

Comment: Considering your mapping your URL should be: http://localhost:8080/project/home/user_page/someUserId

Comment: Hi, I will try to clarify - I want to request a page specific to a user using their userID, so I used the @PathVariable and added the userId at the end of the normal URL. But when I try to access the page, it returns with an URI mapping error for [/professional/home/user_page]. I hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: I got it to work, I was missing a part of the URI. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your case coused by similar mapping for two methods in controllers. As I understood one of the methods has mapping like  "/home/user/setting_page" and another one "/home/user/{userId}". That's why after you have added userId path variable controller tries to parse "setting_page" as userId, and you get this error because such user doesn't exists. Try to change one of this URL in order to make them unique.

**EDIT:**

Ok. As I see from your updates the reason of the problem is that Spring tries to find mapping for url "home/user_page" but it can't because you don't have method with such mapping in controllers. If you want to display JSP (or html) as a result of this method call then you should define InternalViewResolver in your config file and return name of the page. Here is [tutorial](http://shreymalhotra.me/blog/tutorial/springmvc/spring-mvc-hello-springworld-understanding-the-code/) where among other described how to use InternalViewResolver.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry I made an error, the URL I want is  localhost:8080/project/home/user/{userId}. So when a user clicks on link they are taken to a specific page with their user id and a list of modules. This is the URL I have as a value in my controller method.

Comment: I eddited my post after you have provided more info.  I hope this will help you.